# What does "DMV" refer to?

Tags: meaning

Could you please tell me what does "DMV" refer to in the following text:

For your billionaire friend, resources would hold out a tad longer. He or she would have a full-time job spending $50,000 a day for 55 years.
Approximately two generations. Almost 14 presidential terms. One wait to hear your name called at the DMV.

Is it anything culture-specific in the US or a universal acronym?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final sentence fragment, “One wait to hear your name called at the DMV.”, is a culturally-dependent joke in many areas of the United States; ***DMV*** is a standard abbreviation for ***Department of Motor Vehicles***, which is what the agency responsible for issuing vehicle registrations and driver's licenses is called in many states. (In some states, it is called ***MVA***, ***Motor Vehicle Administration***, and there may be other names for it - but ***DMV*** happens to be almost universally understood in the United States.)

(*The joke - really, black humor - is that waiting for your turn at the DMV often takes much longer than you think it should, sometimes hours.)*

Answer (score 2):

DMV stands for "Department of Motor Vehicles", which in the US is commonly the name of the state-level bureaucratic agency that deals with driver's licenses, vehicle registration, etc. DMVs tend to have notoriously poor service and long wait times, which is why the author of this passage likens a 55-year span to "one wait" at the DMV.

Comment: Excellent parallel.